# How to use Boolean in JEST test class

Tags: jestjs

I'm using jest with a very simple search in the text file and but my jest test never passed and 
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here and I have also tried with `toBe` and I still get the same error.

Here is my code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

var isFound = false; 

test("searching in file", () => {
// actual test
fs.readFile(__dirname+'/files/test.txt', "utf8", (err, data) => {

    if (err) throw err;

    const fileStream = data.toLowerCase();
    if(fileStream.includes('awesome')){
        //console.log('found in file');
        isFound = true;
    } else {
        isFound = false;
        //console.log('not found in file');
    } 
})
    expect(isFound).toEqual(true); 
});
```

ERROR:

> 18 |         })
>
> ```
>   19 |         //expect(found).toEqual(true);
>
> > 20 |         expect(isFound).toEqual(true);
>
>      |                         ^
>
>   21 |  
>
>   22 | 
>
>   23 |   });
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try `fs.readFileSync`.  The problem is that your test is asynchronous, so the `expect` happens before the file is read.

Also, `readFileSync` is returning a stream and you need to call `toString()`.

```
const fileStream  = fs.readFileSync(__dirname+'/files/test.txt').toString().toLowerCase();
```

Comment: Thanks I did not thought about that, I changed it to fs.readFileSync and I get the same error.

Comment: Well then there's likely a second problem -- like maybe your stream doesn't actually contain "awesome".  Try `console.log(fileStream)` to print what you're getting.

Comment: What's the solution then?

Comment: Almost a year later, I realize the problem was a likely a missing `toString` call, so I edited my answer.